# Python script which stop start virtual machines by labels on GCP based on scheduler

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, terraform, label, github-actions

Terraform manages all my virtual machines on GCP.

There is a part of them where I would like to add a label that describes who is allowed to be shut down after 18:00 by a Python script.

Therefore, I need a Python script that stops a virtual machine with a specific label, a bucket to store the script, cloud functions to run the script, and a scheduler to trigger the script at a specific time.

Or, If GitHub actions could do the same

Answer (score 2):

I posted an answer to this on the Google Community forums a while back, so here it is:

Below is the python code, so you will have to turn it into a Cloud Function and then use Cloud Scheduler to run it on a schedule.  You can use something similar to start your instances as well.

You will need `google-api-python-client==2.31.0`

```
import json
import googleapiclient.discovery


compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')

result = compute.instances().list(project='mygcpproject-123', zone='northamerica-northeast2-a').execute()
#print(json.dumps(result, indent=2))


#print(len(result)) #returns: 4 (id, items, selfLink, kind)
vms_list=result['items']
num_vms=len(vms_list)

# loop through your instances list and find the ones with 'save_money' in the output (which is your label's key name -- it doesn't matter what the value is)
for i in range(num_vms):
    if "save_money" in json.dumps(vms_list[i]):
        print("stopping {}".format(vms_list[i]['name']))
        compute.instances().stop(project='mygcpproject-123', zone='northamerica-northeast2-a', instance=vms_list[i]['name']).execute()
```